# Can data be transformed in the way below using SQL? I'm not sure a pivot would even work

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

The users want the data to be shown like this:

```
Tax       Description             ML   Total    Link  Link      Link     Link      Link     Link
Code                                   Rate     Code  Rate               Rate      Code     Rate

SC001     Abbeville County, SC    Y    0.0700   SC    0.0600    SCLO1    0.0100
SC002     Aiken County, SC        Y    0.0800   SC    0.0600    SCCP1    0.0100    SCEC1    0.0100
```

But the data is stored in the database like this:

```
Tax     Description             ML  Link            Link
Code                                Rate    Link    Description

SC001   Abbeville County, SC    Y   0.0600  SC      South Carolina State            
SC001   Abbeville County, SC    Y   0.0100  SCLO1   Local Option 1%                 
SC002   Aiken County, SC        Y   0.0600  SC      South Carolina State            
SC002   Aiken County, SC        Y   0.0100  SCCP1   Capital Projects 1%             
SC002   Aiken County, SC        Y   0.0100  SCEC1   Education Capital Improvement
```

I get how to use pivot but what's stumbling me is the fact that they want to see the link then the rate beside it for each tax code. Is that even possible?

I'm doing this in SQL Server 2012 and using SSRS or Crystal Reports, whichever can accomplish this.

Comment: Look for questions mentioning dynamic pivot. It is possible, but quite messy

Comment: I have done a dynamic pivot before but I've never done it where the data lines up the way they want it. Is that possible with dynamic pivot?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have no more than 3 link codes?  If so, you can do it without a pivot or dynamic SQL using just standard joins.

Comment: No, there are multiple link codes, more than 3.

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar in SQL.  Here is my code - I did not modify it to fit your columns, but it should be a good starting point.

```
SELECT  [report_id]
  ,[id]
  ,[label]
  ,[rate]
  ,[per_trip]
  ,[per_mile]
  ,[per_hour]
  ,[per_year]
 FROM Table1

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Column1Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Column2Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @Column1Name= ISNULL(@Column1Name + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(label + ' Column1')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT label FROM [costmodel].[tractor_cost_report] ) AS Labels

SELECT @Column2Name= ISNULL(@Column2Name + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(label + ' Column2')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT label FROM [costmodel].[tractor_cost_report] ) AS Labels

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
-- the Column Names in the query are the values of the [label] field in the rows of data
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N' SELECT id,
    MAX([Wages and Benefits PerTrip]) as WagesBenefitsAmt,      
    MAX([Fuel & Oil PerTrip]) as FuelOilAmt,    
    MAX([Licence PerTrip]) as LicenceAmt,
    MAX([Insurance PerTrip]) as InsuranceAmt,       
    MAX([Monthly Payment PerTrip])  as MonthlyPaymentAmt,
    MAX([Profit PerTrip]) as ProfitAmt,
    MAX([WCB (%) Rate]) as WCBRate,
    MAX([WCB (%) PerTrip]) as WCBAmt,
    MAX([EI ($) PerTrip]) as EIAmt,
    MAX([CPP ($) PerTrip]) as CPPAmt,
    MAX([Statutory Holiday ($) PerTrip]) as StatPayAmt,
    MAX([Vacation (%) Rate]) as VacationRate,
    MAX([Vacation (%) PerTrip]) as VacationAmt,
    MAX([Pension ($) Rate]) as PensionRate,
    MAX([Pension ($) PerTrip]) as PensionAmt

FROM (
    SELECT id, 
        rate,
        per_trip,
        label + '' PerTrip'' as RowPivot1,
        label + '' Rate'' as RowPivot2 
    FROM [Table1] ) a
PIVOT(SUM(per_trip) 
      FOR RowPivot1 IN (' + @Column1Name + ')) AS PVTTable1
PIVOT(SUM(rate) 
      FOR RowPivot2 IN (' + @Column2Name + ')) AS PVTTable2 
GROUP BY id'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
print @DynamicPivotQuery
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be no more than 3 links, you do not need dynamic SQL.  But you can modify this to use Dynamic SQL to add as many as you need, or you can just put as many link fields as you could possibly need (or will fit on your report page).

```
select TaxCode, 
    Description, 
    ML, 
    SUM(LinkRate) TotalRate,
    max(Case when LinkNo=1 then Link end) Link1,
    max(Case when LinkNo=1 then LinkRate end) LinkRate1,
    max(Case when LinkNo=2 then Link end) Link2,
    max(Case when LinkNo=2 then LinkRate end) LinkRate2,
    max(Case when LinkNo=3 then Link end) Link3,
    max(Case when LinkNo=3 then LinkRate end) LinkRate3
from
    (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by TaxCode, Description, ML Order by Link) LinkNo
    from #table
    ) Links
group by TaxCode, Description, ML
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in crystal reports.

1. Group by tax code.
2. For all columns create `if` statements as below

For e.g: for  Description column.

```
    if taxcode=Sc001
    then  Description
else if taxcode=Sc002
    then  Description
```

like wise for all columns and you get the required output.

Comment: This would only work if I knew what all the codes are ahead of time though right? I'd like to make this solution as generic as possible so it will run whether there's 1 code or 10.

Comment: Yes this approach is kind of hard coding the data in crystal reports.... if i know the whole design then generic way can be thought of

Comment: I really don't want to hard code anything if I can avoid it. The way they want to see the data is in the original question as is the way the data returns from the selection query.